# Loading a webapp in different environments

Tags: jquery, web-applications, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a webapp that is hosted online. I also have setup a firefox and chrome extension to load this webapp in a sidebar/popup.

When I open the sidebar in the browser it takes about 2 seconds for the webapp to appear in the sidebar.

What would be a good way to show the user that the webapp is loading? Do I have to put he "loading..." script in the webapp itself or in the browser extension?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I vote for the browser extension

Comment: This reminds me of the McAfee Total Protection webapp. Whenever you load a new page, almost the first thing that loads is a spinner that is displayed over a partially transparent div that is absolutely positioned to fill the window. You can dismiss the spinner, or it will of course be hidden automatically by the page when it finishes loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good UI would be to notify the user of what's going on. A simple spinner (http://ajaxload.info) would do the trick. Just show/hide an absolutely positioned div on load :)